¿Cómo incrementar en tiempo de ejecución Delay o Timer para alargar el tiempo de ejecución?
Estoy tratando de realizar el compartimiento del contador que esta en la imagen GIF, he logrado hacerlo con StatefulWidget un Future.delayed colando con 4 segundos para que se ejecute un evento y me actualice el state del bloc y se oculte el widget visibility, el problema es que cuando sigo incrementando el contador hasta 10 y como esta configurado el delayed para que se ejecute solo hasta 4 segundos entonces se cierra y no es el compartamiento original como app de PedidosYa.
He intente incrementar los segundos del delayed ejecutando un evento al momento de usar el contador pero no resulto, si pudieran darme alguna ayuda, aqui les dejo mi código y le agradezco por su tiempo.
class ProductListSreen extends StatefulWidget {
 const ProductListSreen({super.key});

 @override
 State<ProductListSreen> createState() => _ProductListSreenState();
 }

class _ProductListSreenState extends State<ProductListSreen> {


 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {

 final titleStyle = Theme.of(context).textTheme.titleLarge;

 return BlocBuilder<ProductBloc, ProductState>(
  builder: (context, state) {

    if (state.listProduct.isEmpty) {
      return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
    }

    return Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
      children: [

        CategoryHorizontalListview( title: 'Categorias', titleStyle: titleStyle,),

        Container(
          margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10),
          child:  Text('Productos', style: titleStyle)
        ),

        const SizedBox( height: 12),

        Expanded(
          child: GridView.builder(
            shrinkWrap: true,
            gridDelegate: const SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                crossAxisCount: 3,
                childAspectRatio: 0.6,
                crossAxisSpacing: 2,
            ),
            itemCount: state.listProduct.length,
            itemBuilder: (contex, i) =>
              _crearItem(context, state.listProduct[i]),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  },
 );
}

Widget _crearItem(BuildContext context, ProductModel product) {

return Stack(
  children: [
    Card(
      elevation: 0,
      color: Colors.transparent,
      child: InkWell(
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
    
              SizedBox(
                height: 80.0,
                width: double.infinity,
                child: (product.image.isEmpty)
                    ? Image.asset('assets/no-image.jpg')
                    : ClipRRect(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
                        child: FadeInImage(
                          placeholder:
                              const AssetImage('assets/jar-loading.gif'),
                          height: 100.0,
                          width: double.infinity,
                          fit: BoxFit.cover,
                          image: NetworkImage(product.image),
                        )
                    ),
              ),
    
              const SizedBox(height: 8),
              
              SizedBox(
                width: double.infinity,
                child: Text(
                  'Bs. ${product.price}',
                  style: const TextStyle( fontSize: 15, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)
                )
              ),
              SizedBox(
                width: double.infinity,
                child: Text(
                  '${product.title[0].toUpperCase()}${product.title.substring(1)}',
                  style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 12)
                )
              ),
              SizedBox(
                width: double.infinity, 
                child: Text(product.description1,
                  style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 12)
                )
              ),
              Expanded(
                child: SizedBox(
                  width: double.infinity, 
                  child: Text(product.description2,
                    style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 12)
                  )
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        onTap: () {
          context.read<ProductBloc>().add(ProductoEvent(product));
          Navigator.pushNamed(context, 'product');
        },
      ),
    ),

    Positioned(
      right: 7,
      child: SizedBox(
        width: 35,
        height: 35,
        child: OutlinedButton(
          style: OutlinedButton.styleFrom(
            side: const BorderSide( width: 2, color: Color.fromARGB(255, 74, 224, 79)),
            backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
            shape: const CircleBorder(),
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(2),          
          ),
          child: const Icon(Icons.add, color: Color.fromARGB(255, 74, 224, 79)),
          onPressed: (){
            setState(() {
              product.visible = true;
              context.read<ShoopingCartBloc>().add(AddProductEvent(product));
            });
            Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: product.seconds), (){
              if (mounted){
                setState(() {
                  product.visible = false;
                  context.read<ShoopingCartBloc>().add(AddProductEvent(product));
                }); 
              }else{
                product.visible = false;
              }                  
            });
          },
        ),
      ),
    ),

    Visibility(
      visible: product.visible,
      child: Positioned(
        right: 7,
        child: Container(
          height: 38,
          width: 108,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Colors.white,
            border: Border.all( color: const Color.fromARGB(255, 74, 224, 79)),
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5)
          ),
          child: Stack(
            children: [
              Positioned(
                top: -6,
                right: -5,
                child: Row(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: [
                    IconButton(
                      icon: const Icon(Icons.remove_circle_outline, size: 30),
                      color: const Color.fromARGB(255, 74, 224, 79), 
                    onPressed: (){
                      setState(() {
                        product.quantity--;
                        product.seconds = product.seconds + 2;
                        context.read<ProductBloc>().add(OnQuantityUpdate(product));
                      });
                    }
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      width: 20,
                      child: Text( product.quantity.toString(), 
                        style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 15.0)
                      ),
                    ),
                    IconButton(
                      icon: const Icon(Icons.add_circle_outline, size: 30),
                      color: const Color.fromARGB(255, 74, 224, 79), 
                      onPressed: (){
                        setState(() {
                          product.quantity++;
                          product.seconds = product.seconds + 2;
                          context.read<ProductBloc>().add(OnQuantityUpdate(product));
                        });
                      }
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),  
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ],
 );
}

class ProductBloc extends Bloc<ProductEvent, ProductState> {

 final ProductProvider productProvider;
 final CategoryProvider categoryProvider;

 ProductBloc(this.productProvider, this.categoryProvider) : super(const 
 ProductState()) {

  on<GetProductsEvent>( _onGetProducts);
  on<ProductoEvent>( _onProducto);
  on<OnSearchProduct>( _onSearchProduct);
  on<OnQuantityUpdate>( _onQuantityUpdate);
  on<OnTitleQuery>( _onTitleQuery);
  on<OnResetQuery>( _onResetQuery);
  on<OnUltimoQuery>( _onUltimoQuery);

}

void _onGetProducts( GetProductsEvent event, Emitter emit) async{

 final productos = await productProvider.getProductos();

  emit( 
   state.copyWith(
    listProduct: productos,
    listProductRepository: productos
   )
  );
}

void _onProducto( ProductoEvent event, Emitter emit){

 emit(
  state.copyWith(
    product: event.product
  )
 );
}

void _onSearchProduct( OnSearchProduct event, Emitter emit) async{


final query =  state.listProduct.where((element) => element.title.contains( 
 event.query)).toList();

  emit( 
   state.copyWith(
     listProductRepository: query,
   )
  );
}

void _onQuantityUpdate( OnQuantityUpdate event, Emitter emit) async{

 emit(
  state.copyWith(
    listProduct: state.listProduct.map((e) => e.id == event.product.id? event.product : e).toList()
  )
  );
 }
}


